# Why is diff producing different differences when the files are given in the opposite order

Tags: diff

Please check the following two files 
1. [www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ashu/opt1](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ashu/opt1) 
 
2. [www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ashu/opt2](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ashu/opt2)

The output of diff -bB opt1 opt2 is empty, while that of diff -bB opt2 opt1 is non empty, and can be found at: 
 
3. [www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ashu/diff](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~ashu/diff)

Why is this happening?

Comment: I hope you're down voting only as I did not insert hyperlinks. Please help out with the answer if you can.